# Problemas Vue js y api

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una SPA con Vuejs, (router y axios) estoy tratando de obtener una id de un objeto json llamado desde una API, para cuando le de click me de caracteristicas de este, es decir  tengo mi APi de `https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/places` hora de aventura y quiero que cuando le de clic para conocer residentes me salga info de los residentes pero cuando estoy tratando de obtenerla me dice undefined

Qué puedo hacer, le he dado vueltas al codigo y ya mi cerebro no sabe cuál es la mejor manera, por eso acudo aquí.

Este es mi codigo estoy probando con la api de Pokemon que tiene id mas sencillas

```
<template>

    <router-view v-bind:people="PeopleMain" the-title="Where do you wanna go">
    </router-view>
</template>

<script>

    import personDisplay from './person-display.vue';

    export default {
      name: 'app',
      data() {
        return {PeopleMain: []};
      },
      components: { 

        'person-display' : personDisplay
      },
      created: function() {
        var vm = this;
        axios.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
        .then(function(response){

            vm.PeopleMain = response.data.results;

            console.log(response.data.results);

            // for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++ )
            // {
            //   console.log(vm.PeopleMain[i].residents)
            // }
          for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
             vm.PeopleMain[i].newPlacesId = vm.PeopleMain[i].species.url;



           }



 })
      }

    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

El router link

```
<p><router-link :to="`/type/${person.newPlacesId}`">
    City Info
    </router-link></p>
```

Y donde se mostrará la información

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Detail</h1>
    <p>Name: {{resident.name}}</p>
    <p>Fullname: {{resident.fullname}}</p>

  </div>  
</template>

<script>
  import PersonDiplayPlace from './person-display-place.vue';
  import PersonDiplay      from './person-display.vue';

  export default {
    name: 'resident',
    data() {
      return {resident: {}}
    },
    created() {

      var vm = this;
      var id = this.$route.params.id;
      axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/${id}/?format=json`)
      .then(function(response){
        vm.resident = response.data
        console.log(response.data)
      })


    }

  }

</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

Agradecería si alguien me pudiera dar una guía, muchas gracias por la atención

Comment: Hola. decis que te sale undefined. Podrias escribir el response completo en algun lado? prueba crear una variable en el componente que obtiene el pokemon que queres, y despues agrega {{ $tuvariable}} al final del componente para ver que tiene. A esta, asignale el response completo. Tambien veo que en tu axios no estas controlando errores, tal ves la API esta devolviendo un error y nunca te enteraste. Te fijaste si la llamada se hace correctamente y vuelve correctamente en las herramientas de desarrollador de tu navegador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como está un poco confundida de como realizar este proceso, añadiré un ejemplo base para estas peticiones y como renderizar a través de componentes haciendo uso de `Single File Component`, todo esto haciendo uso de la `API` en heroku

En primer lugar deberá tener un archivo de entrada para configurar `vue-router` con sus respectivas rutas. Tendría el siguiente contenido.

**Index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import  index from './components/index';
import  places from './components/places';

//Definimos las rutas y los componentes respectivos
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: index },
    { path: '/places/:id', component: places , name :'pokemonunico'}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Luego los componentes **index.js** , añadí un `nav` básico con `bootstrap 4`, obtenemos la data desde la API , y iteramos con `v-for` y creamos los `route-link`.

```
<template>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">API VueJs</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
                 <router-link to="/" class="nav-link">Inicio</router-link>
              </li>
              <!-- Enlaces a cada uno de los items obtenidos desde la API
              para el parámetro se emplea el método getId para retornar la última parte
              de la URl para posteriromente hacer la Petición -->
              <li v-for="item in items"  class="nav-item"><router-link  class="nav-link" :to="{ name: 'pokemonunico', params: { id: getId(item.url) }}" >{{item.name}}</router-link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'index',
        data () {
            return {
                items : []
            }
        },
        created(){
            var vm = this;
            axios.get('https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/places/')
            .then(function(response){
                // Asignamos el Array retornado
                vm.items = response.data;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        methods : {
            // método para obtener la última parte de la URL
            getId : function(item){
                let url = item.split('/');
                return  url.pop() || url.pop();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Y por último el componente **places.js** , el acceso a los datos es básico. a partir de eso en el array `item` tendrá todo lo que retorna su `API`,  y podrá acceder a las propiedades que desee o crear más componentes.

```
<template>

    <div>
        <div v-if="item.length ===0"> Cargando...</div>
        <div v-if="item.length !==0">
            <h5> Nombre </h5> 
            <p>{{ item.name}}</p>
            <h5> Residentes </h5> 
            <ul>
                <li v-for="el in item.residents">{{ el}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'places',
        data () {
            return {
                item : []
            }
        },
        created(){
            var vm = this;
            // Obtenemos la información de ese id pasado por parámetro
            // y se le asigna al array item , con esto ya podrá acceder a todas 
            // las propiedades del Array
            axios.get('https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/places/' + this.$route.params.id)
            .then(function(response){
              vm.item = response.data;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Como información adicional si es que emplea `Laravel` sabrá que existe un archivo `bootstrap.js` donde se importa `axios` y demás , será necesario añadir una configuración para los `headers` , añadiendo una nueva clave de la que ya existe .

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf8';
```

Y remover o comentar donde se añade al headers el `token_csrf` ya que no es necesario , es decir

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
```